# What's the start state of C's BNF?

Tags: bnf

I can't know which is the start state in [C's BNF](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/)

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

It's the non-terminal named "translation-unit".

Comment: Every BNF grammar has an initial non-terminal, which expands (with other non-terminals and terminals symbols) to what the language accepts. In C, the initial non-terminal is named "translation-unit".

Comment: I mean ,the final executable is made up of several translation-unit,not a single one.

Comment: Well, after a close look, this C grammar is a bit different from the others I have seen. Not saying it's wrong (you can define the same language in many ways), but in C grammars I have seen the initial non-terminal is translation-unit. You can have more than one translation unit becouse it usually is a recursive definition (see this grammar http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/profs/informatique/Jean-Jacques.Levy/poly/mainB/node23.html). The initial state will be a state meaning that the parser is to accept a translation-unit non-terminal, note that a translation-unit may contain another.

Comment: The BNF you provided is totally different,why?

Comment: Like I said, there are more than one way to define the same language. The BNF I provided is for an LALR parser, if your grammar will be used with another parser type, it may need some changes.